# Applications Insights not sending HTTP request metrics

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

I have integrated Applications Insights in an MVC project (.Net 4.5.2) as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net) . Running it locally and deploying on my local IIS seems fine (all metrics appear on Azure's Application Insights resource.

When I deploy the app on a remote server's IIS I can only see Depenedencies metrics (SQL data in my case). No HTTP request metrics are being sent.

The application insights config file is the same and running the Application Insights Status Monitor doesn't report any issues (it shows the IIS application as enabled and sending the telemetry to the correct resource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check always is that the instrumentation key being used in the app is what you expect when it gets deployed, and second, that all of the application insights binaries *and the config file* got deployed as well.

it might be that status monitor is configured on that machine to send data to one place (a prod resource), hence you see the dependencies, but the deployed app itself is sending it somewhere else (a dev resource?).

if you have access to machine it is getting deployed to, you could run fiddler and see where Application Insights is sending its traffic (look for outbound calls to dc.services.visualstudio.com)

Comment: Yes, the config file was missing some config when compared with the local one. Thanks!